# Is it possible to access R objects from existing session in C#

Tags: c#, r

I'm looking to add a feature to my C# app to be able to open the data objects of an existing R sessions data objects. I've tried out .NET libraries R.NET and RserveCLI2 which indeed interact with the installed R application to be able to launch their own sessions and run R commands, but I am yet to find out if it is possible to access an R session that is already open (in RStudio for example).

From my understanding R objects are stored in memory, and not on disk like SAS datasets are. Is it even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: While I don't know if this is possible, wouldn't if be easier to save and retrieve these objects from a file? Alternatively, have you looked at how `rstudioapi::viewer()` handles opening objects?

Comment: perhaps have a look at : https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html

Comment: indeed it's easier to retrieve the objects from file, however my use case doesn't guarantee that the users have saved their files. The feature I'm looking to add is to open dataframes and matrices from any current R session.I will look into those links

Comment: I've had a look through those projects, but didn't find how they handle accessing objects unfortunately